# Showing labels of feature on the edge of screen

Tags: qgis, labeling

My QGIS only shows labels on the center area. How to show labels of feature on the edge?
[image]

[image]

Comment: isn't it a **point** layer ? what do u call an **'edge'** then ? edge of a point ? or edge of the symbol u used in the symbology ? Hard to see on your screenshot ...

Comment: Just a wild guess... in the Labels - `Rendering`, there is a `Limit number of features to be labeled to` option, which is usually unchecked. If you have set it to some number, let's say 300, QGIS will post labels to only first 300 features found in the attribute table. Your outposted points may have exceeded this limit. Please check the setting.

Comment: @snaileater it's a point layer, i don't know why only feature in the center part of screen can show labels, but  point feature on the peripheral  can't?  i add a picture more cleary, thank you

Comment: @kazuhito i try to uncheck this option, or set the limit number to 2000. Both  can't  work.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you still use 2.8? Otherwise my first suggestion would be to update to at least 2.18, the latest release of 2.x.

Comment: Interesting... no idea, but could you tell us a little bit about the numbers in bold text (**29**, **28**,... **25**) at the top? For some reason I am getting bothered by them, as the location of these numbers coincides with the labeled points. Sorry...

Comment: @MrXsquared I keep 2.8 version for Points2One plugin. i am not familiar with qgis, and  this problem happened suddenly , i think maybe some default setting was accidentally change. thanks your suggestion.

Comment: @Kazuhito bold text(29, 28,... 25) is another point layer  that symbol without filling color

Comment: I see. Thanks for your clarification. I understand I cannot provide any solution, and upgrading QGIS suggested by @MrXsquared would be the best option. FWIW, I tested Points2One plugin on QGIS 2.18.28 and it seems  working. QGIS 2.18.28 among other older QGIS versions can be found at [repo](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/).